# Why do python statements end with : (colon)?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the purpose of the colon before a block in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215581/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-colon-before-a-block-in-python)

I've just done a bit of research on Python and am intrigued by the language construct.

```
if expression:
    print 1
    ...
    print 2
```

I'm surprised and impressed that python group commands for a statement by indentation. It seems as though the designers said we don't need/want extra characters such as { ... } in C and End If in VB.

But why do statements end with : (colon)? Seems superfluous given the lack of an end delimiters.