# Syntax error iterating over tuple in python

Tags: python, tuples, python-2.7

I am new to Python and am unsure of the best way to iterate over a tuple.

The syntax

```
for i in tuple
    print i
```

causes an error. Any help will be much appreciated! I am a ruby programmer new to python.

Comment: This is the sort of question that makes google users hate SO.  The title sounds so useful (and something one would google), but the question is so trivial and un-informative.

Comment: btw, this is the top hit for 'best way to iterate over tuples in python'

Answer (score 37, accepted):

That is an error because the syntax is invalid, add a colon:

```
for i in tup:
    print i
```

Also, you should not use `tuple` as the name for a variable, as it is the name of a [built-in function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#tuple).

Comment: One really nice way to avoid using reserved names for variables is to use Pylint (http://www.pylint.org/) to check your code every time you save. I use Aptana with Pydev and Pylint to do this.

Answer (score 5):

```
for i in my_tuples_name:
    print i
```

You don't iterate over the keyword tuple, you iterate over your variable.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to have forgotten a colon.

```
for i in my_tuple:
    print i
```

Also look at [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215581/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-colon-before-a-block-in-python/215676#215676).

**EDIT:** And I didn't notice you were iterating over the keyword `tuple`, [as noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264073/the-best-way-to-iterate-over-a-tuple-in-python/7264090#7264090). by [F.J.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505154/f-j) and [Jakob Bowyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/462604/jakob-bowyer).