# What is wrong with this multiple condition if statement?

Tags: python, if-statement

Given the example

```
if row[3] == ' male' & row[5] == 0 & row[6] == 0;
```

i want to check more than one variable , it keeps on giving me an error
can someone politely right an example code of how to accomplish this

Comment: be useful to know the error don't you think?Also what are you trying to do here, there's no context to your question

Comment: Read here :  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/

Answer (score 1):

By using the `and` keyword or `&` character as you have done:-

```
if row[3] == 'male' and row[5] == 0 and row[6] == 0:
if row[3] == 'male' & row[5] == 0 & row[6] == 0:
```

However, you've used a [semi-colon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335358/python-what-does-a-semi-colon-do) (`;`) at the end of your `if` statement, when it should have been a [colon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215581/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-colon-before-a-block-in-python) (`:`) which tells your Python interpreter to expect indented code.  A semi colon terminates a statement, only really used in Python when you want to put two statements on one line. In this case it will not execute the intended `if` "block"

**For future reference:**

If you are asking questions on StackOverflow about an error, post the error in case you have misunderstood its intention like in this case.

Comment: Thank you , im just new to python hahaha :D

Comment: Never used `&` in Python but fair enough, expanded my answer.

Comment: @AyushShanker Be careful - `&` means "bitwise and", which is not equivalent to `and` (i.e. "logical and"). In this case, since each of the conditional statements evaluates to a boolean, `&` will give the same result as `and`, but this is not necessarily true for other types. For example, `(1 and 2) == 2` whereas `(1 & 2) == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

while the other answer is better, you can also use `&` (bitwise and operator):

```
if (row[3] == ' male') & (row[5] == 0) & (row[6] == 0):
```

Answer (score 0):

To use multiple conditions use the `and` keyword

`if (row[3] == ' male' and row[5] == 0 and row[6] == 0):`

The `()` make it easier to read. Also you need to use `:` instead of `;`.

Comment: Personally I would enclose each conditional statement in parentheses, e.g.: `if (row[3] == ' male') and (row[5] == 0) and (row[6] == 0):`, but this is more of a stylistic point.

Comment: The format of the the enclosure is up to personal opinion but I do it this way because the format is similar to c based languages which most programmers are familiar with, making it easy to read.

Comment: I see. My reasoning for having parens around each comparison is that they make the order of operations obvious, e.g. `... (row[5] == 0) and (row[6] == 0) ...` rather than `... row[5]) == (0 and row[6]) == (0 ...`. In this case it's trivial, but for more complex expressions I find that they can help a lot with clarity.