# Name delimiter `:` in a meaning way

Tags: python

In the following code:

```
In [5]: if 2 > 1 & 1 > 0:
   ...:     print("True")
   ...:     
True
```

I know that:
`>` is comparative operator,
`&` is logic/bitwise operator,
`=` is assignment operator,

How about colon `:` ? How could I name it an abstract concept rather than colon:

```
In [6]: def foo(): return 3
In [7]: foo()
Out[7]: 3
```

In the above codes, `:` act as `=` assignment.

I checked the official docs[2. Lexical analysis — Python 3.6.6 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html)

```
2.6. Delimiters
The following tokens serve as delimiters in the grammar:

(       )       [       ]       {       }
,       :       .       ;       @       =       ->
+=      -=      *=      /=      //=     %=      @=
&=      |=      ^=      >>=     <<=     **=
The period can also occur in floating-point and imaginary literals.
```

I noticed that all the delimiters have appropriate meaning: ( for tuple, [ for list constructor, @ for decorator, `,` for true delimiter, `.` for attribute access.

Excluding `:`?

How could I name it in a meaning way?

Comment: The colon in end of the line of the code block is for `indentation`. May be you can look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215581/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-colon-before-a-block-in-python

Comment: FYI `&` is only the bitwise operator. `and` is the logic operator.

Comment: If there's no explicit name in the language definition, then it might have none and you just call it "colon".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:` is simply part of the syntax of a compound statement that indicates the end of the clause header.

From the documentation of [compound statements](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#compound-statements):

> Compound statements consist of one or more ‘clauses.’ A clause
>   consists of a header and a ‘suite.’ The clause headers of a particular
>   compound statement are all at the same indentation level. Each clause
>   header begins with a uniquely identifying keyword and ends with a
>   ***colon***.