# What is the term for a colon before a suite in Python syntax?

Tags: python, syntax, naming-conventions, python-internals

I want to know what the technical term for a colon in the context of introducing a suite after a statement is called. I do not mean colons in slices, key-value pairs or type hints, but this kind of usage:

```py
if True:
    pass
else:
    pass

try:
    raise
except:
    pass

def foo():
    pass

lambda: ...  # I don't know if this is appertaining
```

I did not really find a fitting term online. Most only call them colons, while expecting the reader to understand the meaning of a colon in this context in Python. I found [this website](https://skillapp.co/blog/mastering-the-colon-operator-in-python-a-comprehensive-guide/) which uses the term "colon operator", but that doesn't feel right to me - especially as it lumps together all uses of colons under that umbrella term. I apologise if I have missed an obvious answer somewhere.

Comment: There isn't a term. It's just how the end of the clause header is delimited: [_"Each clause header begins with a uniquely identifying keyword and ends with a colon."_](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html) (No, lambdas aren't included, they're an [expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda); and it's certainly not an operator.)

Comment: If you knew a term for it, how would you use it?

Comment: @KellyBundy I wanted to use the term to differentiate between this kind of usage of colons and other usages (like in type hints) in a text about Python syntax. I guess I just have to explicitly say that I mean "a colon at the start of a block".

Comment: The syntactical function of the colon is to let you write  single-line blocks on the same line, e.g. `if foo == bar: continue`. It's still required for nested blocks,, but I assume that's for consistency, the language *could* have been defined to not require it, since the indentation is unambiguous. To actually answer your question, I'd try to talk more about blocks or suites (as they are the important bit) than colons in most cases.

Comment: Any time you have a structure like `KEYWORD expression ':' block` you have the colon to separate the expression from the block, because there is no requirement that there be a newline/indent, you can cram it on one line if you really want. @kindall you beat me by one second :P

Comment: @kindall Yes, I know about that. (You can read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215581/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-colon-before-a-block-in-python) to find more arguments against and for colons in that context)
I agree, in any other context I'd also talk about blocks. But I wanted to know this not because of the block, but rather I wanted to address the colon itself, and where it should be placed. I was simply wondering if there is a proper name for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simply called a "colon" `:`, but I might say and the grammar spec suggests you'd say something like "the start of a *block*"

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html

> ```
> # COMPOUND STATEMENTS
> # ===================
>
> # Common elements
> # ---------------
>
> block:
>     | NEWLINE INDENT statements DEDENT 
>     | simple_stmts
> ```